# How to SELECT * from a table when looking to see if a particular column has two unique values in another column with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, having-clause

I have MySQL query I'm trying to run but I can't figure out how to approach it. My example data I'm working with is this

```
TABLE called Stop
COLUMNS of ID, STATION_ID, NAME_ID
ROWS OF DATA (1, 5, 4), (1, 6, 6), (1, 3, 2), (2, 9, 4), (3, 10, 20), (1, 12, 15), (4, 1, 3)
```

I'm trying to query for two STATION_ID that exist for one particular ID from the Stop table where the STOP ID has to have both STATION_ID or else it won't return anything

I had `SELECT id FROM stop WHERE station_ID = 5 AND station_ID = 6` but this doesn't work. What kind of query parameters do I need to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select id
from stop
where station_id in (5, 6)
group by id
having count(*) = 2
```

If there are duplicate `(id, station_id)`, then you need `count(distinct station_id)` instead of `count(*)`.